# Let $F$ be a finite field. Then the multiplicative group $(F \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field. I'm trying to prove

> The multiplicative group $(F \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ is cyclic.

Then I figure out that it's sufficient to prove

> Different multiplicative subgroups of $F$ have different orders.

I would like to prove it by myself, but fail after one week of trying. Could you please leave me some **minimal hints** so that I can go on?

---

**Update:** I've just figured out that it's sufficient to prove

> For any divisor $d$ of $|F \setminus \{0\}|$, there is at least one multiplicative cyclic subgroup of order $d$.

Comment: Sometimes generalizing helps to disregard irrelevant details. Try to show for **any** field $F$, any  **finite** multiplicative subgroup of $F^\times$ is cyclic.

Comment: To expand on this hint, if $d \mid |F^\times|$, how many elements of $F^\times$ have order $d$?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop for a cyclic subgroup of order $d$, there is $\varphi(d)$ generators in this subgroup. The problem is how to prove that there is at least one multiplicative cyclic subgroup of order $d$. Please see my update.

Comment: Can you use $\sum_{d | n} \phi(d) = \phi(n)$ somehow ?

Comment: @Lelouch Do you mean $\sum_{d | n} \phi(d) = n$?

Comment: @LAD Yes, sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @LAD: Are you aware that in any abelian group, if there are elements of $m$ and $n$, then there is an element of order $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$?

Comment: @Lelouch Actually, I intend to combine *for any divisor $d$ of $|F \setminus \{0\}|$, there is at least one multiplicative cyclic subgroup of order $d$* and that formula.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Yes. Actually, that fact is an essential argument in my attempt.

Comment: @LAD Try showing for any abelian group $G$, if the equation $nx = e$ has atmost $n$ solutoins, then $G$ is cyclic. How does the problem follow from here ?

Comment: @LAD: great, I have added a hint. (You need to use the fact mentioned for part 2.)

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $F^\times = F\setminus\{0\}.$
Let $l = \operatorname{lcm}\{\operatorname{order}(x) \mid x \in F^\times\}.$
Let $n = |F^\times|.$

1. Consider the polynomial $x^l - 1$. How many roots does this have in $F$? What can you conclude?

> $n \le l.$

2. Consider an element $g \in F^\times$ such that $\operatorname{order}(g) = l.$ (Why does this exist?)
   What can you conclude?

> $l \mid n$ and hence, $n = l.$ Thus, $g$ is an element of order $n$ and therefore, must generate $F^\times$.

Comment: I've just posted my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745040/any-multiplicative-subgroup-of-finite-fields-is-cyclic). Could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $d$ be a divisor of the order of $F^*$.

How many solution has at most the equation $x^d-1=0$?

Then it is easy to reduce what you need to the identity for $\varphi$  in the comments..