# A multiplicative group in which there are more than $n$ elements satisfying the equation $x^n=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my proof in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745040/any-multiplicative-subgroup-of-a-finite-field-is-cyclic?noredirect=1#comment7701086_3745040), I use the fact that a nonconstant polynomial of degree $m$ over a field has at most $m$ different roots. As such, I would like to ask for an example of a multiplicative group such that there are more than $n$ elements satisfying the equation $x^n=1$.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To the downvoter, please mention the reason for your downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abelian groups give many examples. For example, for any $n$, take $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$, which has $n^k$ elements, all of which satisfy $x^n=1$. You can even take an infinite product, so the number of such $x$ can be infinite as well.

There are many other examples. For one non-abelian example, there is a group of order $27$ that is not abelian such that $x^3=1$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

For an easy example, you may consider the Klein-four group and then the equation $x^2=1$ will have $4>2$ solutions.